# How to implement an increment method on pairs

Tags: java, increment, circular-list

I am working on a circular linked list and have implemented the following method to increment the elements of the list by a given value.

```
 public void IncrementList(E e) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Node<E> temp = current;

        do {
            Double res = temp.element.doubleValue() +  e.doubleValue();
            temp.element = (E) res;
            temp = temp.next;
        } while (temp != current);
    }
}
```

This method works fine with lists of doubles; however, now I am trying to use it on a list of pairs but I keep getting an error since the method is used for doubles.
What should I do to change this method and let it accept pairs and increment them.
The following is the pair class I implemented:

```
public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    int x, y;
    
    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
    if (this.x > o.x)
        return 1;
    if (this.x < o.x)
        return -1;
    else 
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what error are you getting? From what you have now, it seems you’ll need to implement a special interface for the objects your list can store in order to handle this.

Comment: This is my expected output: before increment:
List1 = [(10,10), (50,50), (50,50)]
after increment:
List1.IncrementList(p10)
List1 = [(20,20), (60,60), (60,60)]

Comment: The error I am getting is that pair can't be cast to java.lang.double, I can create a separate interface that my class will implement but what should I add in that interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce an interface `Incrementable` like this one:

```java
/**
 * Interface for objects that can be "incremented" by values 
 * from another object
 * @param <E>   element type
 */
public interface Incrementable<E> {
    public E incrementBy(E otherObj);
}
```

When implementing this interface in `Pair` the method can be specified as

```java
@Override
public Pair incrementBy(Pair otherObj) {
    if (otherObj == null) {
        return new Pair(this.getX(), this.getY());
    }
    return new Pair(this.getX() + otherObj.getX(), this.getY() + otherObj.getY());
}
```

Please note that the `IncrementList(E)` method also needs to be changed:

```java
public void IncrementList(E e) {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        Node<E> temp = current;
        do {
            E increasedValue = temp.element;
            if ((e instanceof Incrementable) && (temp.element instanceof Incrementable)) {
                increasedValue = ((Incrementable<E>)temp.element).incrementBy((E)(Incrementable<E>)e);
            } else {
                // perform increment on other types?
                //increasedValue = IncrementUtils.increment(temp.element, e);
            }
            if (increasedValue != null) {
                temp.element = increasedValue;
            }
            temp = temp.next;
        } while (temp != current);
    }
}
```

One additional point to consider: should the interface `Incrementable` return new instances of the same type but with values increased (like `BigInteger.add(BigInteger)` does) or should the method work with the values in the object itself (like `StringBuilder.add(...)` does)? It depends on your overall use cases which way to specify this behavior.

The code above assumes that new instances will be used; if you prefer to change the values inside the objects, then the signature in the interface should be `void incrementBy(E)` and the `IncrementList(E)` method does not need to re-assign the increased value after applying the increase.

One last thought: to make the `IncrementList(E)` method work with elements that do not implement `Incrementable` you can use a helper class with a method that handles some other types of objects, especially `Number`s and `String`s. As this classes do not support changing their "internal" values, you need to re-assign the result of the increase call to the list elements.

As a starting point, this helper class could look like this:

```java
public class IncrementUtils {
    
    public static <E> E increment(E obj1, E obj2) {
        if ((obj1 == null) || (obj2 == null)) {
            return null;
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof Integer) && (obj2 instanceof Integer)) {
            return (E)(Integer)(((Integer)obj1) + ((Integer)obj2));
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof Double) && (obj2 instanceof Double)) {
            return (E)(Double)(((Double)obj1) + ((Double)obj2));
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof Long) && (obj2 instanceof Long)) {
            return (E)(Long)(((Long)obj1) + ((Long)obj2));
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof Float) && (obj2 instanceof Float)) {
            return (E)(Float)(((Float)obj1) + ((Float)obj2));
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof BigDecimal) && (obj2 instanceof BigDecimal)) {
            return (E)((BigDecimal)obj1).add((BigDecimal)obj2);
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof BigInteger) && (obj2 instanceof BigInteger)) {
            return (E)((BigInteger)obj1).add((BigInteger)obj2);
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof String) && (obj2 instanceof String)) {
            return (E)((String)obj1 + (String)obj2);
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof StringBuilder) && (obj2 instanceof StringBuilder)) {
            return (E)(new StringBuilder().append(obj1).append(obj2));
        }
        if ((obj1 instanceof StringBuffer) && (obj2 instanceof StringBuffer)) {
            return (E)(new StringBuffer().append(obj1).append(obj2));
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: is there a way to write the same increment method in a recursive form

Comment: The increment method depends on the object that it works on. `IncrementUtils.increment(...)` could work on any object but there needs to be a definition on how this should work on specific types of objects. On the other hand you could use reflection to find all fields on the object and then process them recursively.